# Specify what diagram to display in a generated document

Tags: documentation, diagram, enterprise-architect

I am in the process of creating a document template that has its own sections for each diagram in a package. In my template, I want to only show a specific diagram in a section and display another diagram in a different section elsewhere in the generated document.

- 1.0 Some text
- 1.1 Diagram1
- 1.2 Some more text
- ...
- 1.4 Diagram2
- ...
- 2.5 Diagram3

The issue that I've been running into is that when I insert the fragment into Diagram1 section to call the image with Custom SQL it'll stick every diagram from the package in there rather than the one I need.

I am not sure if I can even display a specific diagram from a Custom SQL but it was the option that made sense to try.

Answer (score 0):

For complex and more customisation you can try document scripts with Doc generator class.

DocumentDiagram method in DocumentGenerator class will help you inserting diagrams inside the RTF documentation.
[image]
More details on [DocumentGenerator class](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/automation/document_generator_interface_class.html)

Refer these blogs to know more about generating complex documentation

- [Generate complex documents from Enterprise Architect with a two-step
  semi-automated approach](https://bellekens.com/2015/11/12/tutorial-generate-complex-documents-from-enterprise-architect-with-a-two-step-semi-automated-approach/)
- [Generating Documents using Document Scripts in Enterprise Architect](https://www.sparxsystems.in/blogs/document-generation-using-document-scripts-in-sparx-enterprise-architect/)

Comment: Try looking at virtual documents first.https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_publishing/virtualdocuments.html This might already solve your problem without the need for any scripting.